# Mozilla and Chrome difference on CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I have a problem with my CSS. It works well on chrome but not on Mozilla Firefox.

My code is getting twitter icon to the left, when mouse is over the icons.

My **HTML** code:

```
<header>

  <div id="animation">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com.tr">
      <img id="socialiconface" src="images/facebook.png">
    </a>

    <a href="http://www.twitter.com.tr">
      <img id="socialicon" src="images/twitter.png">
    </a>
  </div>

</header>
```

And my **CSS** is there:

```
#socialicon {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition-property: margin-right;
  -moz-transition-property: margin-right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 2px;
}

#socialiconface {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 2px;
}

#socialicon:hover {
  margin-right: 70px;
}
```

Whatever I tried, that doesn't work unfortunately, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line to cover the whole animation div, otherwise you will have to follow the icon with your mouse for it to animate bacause it moves away.

```
#animation:hover #socialicon {
    margin-right: 70px;
}
```

Full code:

```css
#socialicon {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition-property: margin-right;
    -moz-transition-property: margin-right;
    -webkit-transition-duration:2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    width:40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 2px;
}
#socialiconface {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 2px;
}
#animation:hover #socialicon {
    margin-right: 70px;
}
img {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="animation">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com.tr"><img id="socialiconface" src="images/facebook.png" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com.tr"><img id="socialicon" src="images/twitter.png" /></a>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because once the img moves past the mouse cursor, the `:hover` style is no longer applied.  Even Chrome does this, but it seems that it doesn't check the `:hover` state until the mouse moves.

You can try animating `right` instead of `margin` and giving some right padding instead:

```css
#socialicon {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  -moz-transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 5px;
  right: -68px;
  padding-right: 70px
}
#socialiconface {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 2px;
}
#socialicon:hover {
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>


  <div id="animation">

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com.tr">
      <img id="socialiconface" src="images/facebook.png">

    </a>

    <a href="http://www.twitter.com.tr">
      <img id="socialicon" src="images/twitter.png">

    </a>
  </div>

</header>
```